# Create Index options explanation (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, indexing, ddl

I have a sql to create composite index in oracle DB. But I can not understand with some words.

```
create index "index01" on “table01”("name","age")
PCTFREE 20 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
STORAGE(INITIAL xxxx NEXT xxxx MINEXTENTS xx MAXEXTENTS xxxx
PCTINCREASE x FREELISTS xx FREELIST GROUPS xx
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "Table-space" ;
```

I am not clear with 'COMPUTE STATISTICS' and must 'COMPUTE STATISTICS','storage','tablespace' be used?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5011.htm)?

Comment: The compute statistics is done automaticaly in 11g, anyway. If you don't specify the tablespace it will be created in the default tablespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `(PCTFREE 20 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255)` - descries how DB block is filled
- `(COMPUTE STATISTICS)` - tells Oracle to gather performance statistics for created index
- `(STORAGE(INITIAL xxxx NEXT xxxx MINEXTENTS xx MAXEXTENTS xxxx PCTINCREASE)` - describes how to allocate disk space to index in datafiles
- `(BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)` - describes how to store index's block into memory (buffer cache).
- `TABLESPACE "Table-space"`  - in that tablespace to create index

Generally to create the index you need only `create index "index01" on "table01"("name","age")` the rest has a default value (you specify the rest parameters only if you want to overwrite the defaults)

Comment: Just a note that `MAXTRANS` is obsolete, nowadays it's always 255 no matter what value is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Al you need to create a basic index is
    create index "index01" on “table01”("name","age");

The rest is optional. Including the last line may be a wise thing, so you can place your indexes in another tablespace.

Comment: and when to use  'COMPUTE STATISTICS '?